# React app, Images not downloading after npm build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack, github-pages

After `npm run build` in **react.js@18 application**. some of the `<img src=‘images/logo.png’>` tag stopped working. I’ve coded exactly same path in 2 react component. but image is not showing in only one component. .

I am using `logo.png` in `<body><nav>` &  `<body><header>` creted by react components.

I’m also using `logo.svg` in `<head>` tag in `index.html`

After npm build and deploy by `gh-pages`, the image in ` does not load.

I can still see image in  which is loded with landing page,

comes when someone click on **Home** NavLink (*Seems some code in react-router is not working. but this question is for image issue..*)

The difference I see in the two logo.png requests is,  My non woring component is trying to load the image as text/HTML as per Chrome-Network-tab,

[image: Chrome network tab]

I found [this article](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/) in official documentation, but my logo.png is outside of src folder. So I can not use `import` in react component. Moreover, its working without import in one component, so I’m unable to figure out.

**---UPDATES---**

Actually now I’m more confused.. the above screenshot of network tab, where the same image was showing in `<nav>` but not in ` was taken when I tried to access the published applicaiton from my github link.

But now I checked, after the deploy, I do not see image in any place on my local.

I thought the `node build` might've updated something, so

- I deleted the code folder on local machine
- Cloned the project again.
- `npm i` followed by `npm start`
- I did not even run `npm build`. But now on my localhost link no image is shown

I’m getting below in chrome-network-tab.
Not sure how everything was working until yesterday.

[image]

**---UPDATE-2---**

(solved with compromise)

As I already mentioned in my question earlier, the link of official documentation required to move the image in src folder.
I followed the instructions

- Moved the image folder in src
- used `import logo from '../../images/logo.png’;` at the top of both my comonent.
- used `<img src={logo} ......>` in components

but thats a compromise.
Please let me know if there is a way to make it work by keeping image under `/public/images/` folder, instead of `src/images`

```
public
 |-> images
       |-> logo.png //Did not work 
src
 |-> images
       |- logo.png // this worked with import clause
     components
       |-> different subfolders containing js files
       |-> ................
       |-> ................
```

Comment: I was sending you here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71812113/uncaught-error-cannot-find-module-file-home-agemiro-backend-gerenciador-uploa/71813604#71813604 but then you said it was working locally so it was weird.
I rememebr gh-pages had some issues with relative/absolute url of assets, but in any case I suggest you to place all your assets inside src and bundle them with webpack loader, or place them into public folder.

Comment: Assets are under under public folder only. under  `public/images/logo.png`, `public` is sibling of `src`

Comment: Also on the deployed applicaiton, the githib link, its working in one component

Comment: I actually followed what was written here in official, but I had to  move the logo in the src folder. `https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/`. I did not want that

Comment: Okay then this is your issue 99% : https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs/issues/1757

Comment: I was able to make it work as per my update-2.  I still have issues with router and few more need to complete before tomorrow morning.. will surely check this afterwards... but thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes as I told you importing them with webpack is the suggested way if you use CRA as they say in docs. The problem if you put assets in public folder is that gh pages uses relative paths for assets, while CRA uses %PUBLIC_URL% env variable which converts to absolute paths.
I found a specific section in cra docs that drive you into how to deploy correctly to ghpages: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#github-pages and expose you this issue.
By adding the homepage entry in package.json could fix the problem with assets in public.

Comment: I did have homepage entry in package.json that is a `must’ve` for deploying on GitHub. but I believe  creating a  js variable for `URL` and using it with image  might do the trick. I’ll check and confirm tomorrow. thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

This problem concerns the gh-pages dependency, the best after having finished sending it to github with the npm run deploy script, you must delete "homepages", and the "gh-pages" dependency then do an npm install